# Taurus/JMeter - total time for thread group execution within pass/fail criteria

Tags: jmeter, performance, api-testing, taurus

I have an end-to-end scenario to include in performance testing that takes a decent length of time to execute. Between releases of the system, this time needs to be monitored to ensure it hasn't increased.

I am already taking advantage of the very useful pass/fail criteria in Taurus. However, the available criteria are quite granular (at the individual request/response level). I know Taurus does output test duration but this could include other items that I'm not interested in. I also can't see test duration supported as a metric for the pass/fail module in Taurus.

So, any suggestions on how to extract the time to complete the process and then compare this time with a pass/fail criterion? The script itself would be executed within Jenkins for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On JMeter level it would be something like:

1. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the tearDown Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def start = vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long

   def end = System.currentTimeMillis()

   if ((end - start) > 5000) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseCode('999')
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Thread group execution took longer than 5 seconds')
   }
   ```
3. That's it, if your Thread Group(s) take longer than 5 seconds - the JSR223 Sampler will be marked as failed and you can catch this event with Pass/Fail Criteria as well

Explanation of the script:

- `vars` - stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and it's used to read the value of `TESTSTART.MS` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) which holds the timestamp of the test start
- `SampleResult` - basically an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class allowing to set response code, message, body, success, etc.

More information on above and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)